# No observations for specific group - group comparison still possible?

Tags: survival, weibull-distribution, recurrent-events

I am conducting a Weibull Survival analysis (recurrent event) with the time-frame between 1970 and 2010. One question is the difference in survival time between gender. However in the earlier years for 1970-1973 there are no women observed. Since calendar year is not my time scale this shouldn't be a problem right? Everyone in my sample starts at zero (onset of risk).

I did inlcude possible period effects as dummy variables (for example new hollywood era and blockbuster era).

Comment: It may depend on whether 1970-1973 was different from later periods (at least for men).  If it was, then you may be biasing your analysis

Comment: @Henry And what if those periods do differ? Is there a way to incorporate that?